# display list of available audio outputs when Bluetooth is connected

Tags: audio, routes, voip, whatsapp

How to display list of available audio outputs when Bluetooth is connected and switch to user selected audio route?

I tried checking AVAudioSession.sharedIntsance().CurrentRoute.outputs, but it always returns only one output route.